# gitea - create repo API

Tags: gitea

trying to create repository via API. using swagger execute mode:

```
curl -X POST "https://URL/git/api/v1/user/repos?access_token=XXXXX" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"auto_init\": true, \"description\": \"blablabla\", \"gitignores\": \"string\", \"issue_labels\": \"string\", \"license\": \"string\", \"name\": \"blablabla\", \"private\": true, \"readme\": \"string\"}"
```

yields 500 error, complains about readme.

```
{"message":"initRepository: prepareRepoCommit: getRepoInitFile[string]: open /readme/string: file does not exist","url":"URLr"}
```

Guess because of this param:

> "readme\": \"string\"

I don’t know what’s the suggested value for that but it’s in swagger docs.
any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default json body params supplied by swagger are not working.

This did the trick:

```
{
  "auto_init": true,
  "description": "blablabla",
  "gitignores": "",   <--- empty string instead of defaults
  "issue_labels": "", <--- empty string instead of defaults
  "license": "",      <--- empty string instead of defaults
  "name": "ccc2",
  "private": true,
  "readme": ""        <--- empty string instead of defaults
}
```

Comment: Hi, how did you figure it out? I have the same issue with access tokens deletion using API. I always get 401 error, even though I am authenticated. It seems for me that something in swagger is not correct here?